# Webpage doesn't adjust to any screen height automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

I had an issue with the blank space below the footer. I've managed to solve this by adding a jQuery sticky footer as the CSS methods doesn't work for me.

However, I do have a problem with main content of the webpage. If I adjust .bg-photo's height, it will affect how low or high the footer's placement will go.

Any content within .bg-photo will not affect the footer's placement at all.

I'm thinking it could be my HTML or CSS that's doing this sort of issue. Although, I'm not sure.

What I want is that the page automatically adjust to any screen's height and the user doesn't have to scroll down to view just the footer.

Here's the webpage:
http://planet.nu/dev/test/index.html

Here's the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mqfrnjaa/

And the codes if you need to view them right away.

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
       
       var footerHeight = 0,
           footerTop = 0,
           $footer = $(".footer");
           
       positionFooter();
       
       function positionFooter() {
       
                footerHeight = $footer.height();
                footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";
       
               if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "absolute"
                   }).animate({
                        top: footerTop
                   })
               } else {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "static"
                   })
               }
               
       }

       $(window)
               .scroll(positionFooter)
               .resize(positionFooter)
               
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 600px;
}
body * {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #393c3d;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#fw_header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
}
#fw_header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.forums #fw_header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#fw_header ul {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
#fw_header li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
#fw_header li a {
    padding: 0 8px;
}
#fw_header li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #829AC6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#fw_header li a.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #4E6CA3;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu li a.active,
#fw_header ul.subsubmenu li a.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #829AC6;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu,
#fw_header ul.subsubmenu {
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu_usage {
    padding-left: 32px;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu_plugins {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu_development {
    padding-left: 23px;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu_extras {
    padding-left: 14px;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu_testing {
    padding-left: 480px;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu_styling {
    padding-left: 80px;
}
#fw_header ul.subsubmenu {
    padding-left: 120px;
}
#fw_header ul.submenu li,
#fw_header ul.subsubmenu li {
    font-size: 80%;
}
#fw_header {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#fw_header a {
    color: #4E6CA3 !important;
}
#fw_header h1 {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.45em;
    margin-top: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#fw_header h1 img {
    margin-top: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#fw_header h1 a {
    color: black !important;
}
#fw_header h1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header_options {
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;
    top: -32px;
    width: 495px;
}
#header_options .option {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 165px;
}
#header_options a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header_options .option:hover {
    background-color: #F5F7FA;
}
#header_options div.option img {
    margin-right: 7px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#header_options .option table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_options .option table td {} #header_options #options_search {
    padding: 7px 0;
    width: 495px;
}
#header_options #options_download {} #options_search input[type="text"] {
    height: 20px;
    width: 350px;
}
#header_download {
    background: url("../images/dl_button_220.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 36px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -8px;
    width: 220px;
}
#header_donate {
    background: url("../images/donate_button.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 36px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -8px;
    width: 220px;
}
#header_download a,
#header_donate a {
    color: white;
}
#header_download a:hover,
#header_donate a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#dontate_wrapper {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    border: 1px dotted #A5A5A5;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#header_advert {
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -32px;
    width: 150px;
}
body .adpacks {} body .one .bsa_it_ad {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
body .one .bsa_it_ad:hover {
    background-color: #F5F7FA;
    color: black;
}
body .one .bsa_it_ad .bsa_it_i {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
body .one .bsa_it_ad .bsa_it_d {
    font-size: 11px !important;
}
body .one .bsa_it_ad .bsa_it_i img {
    border: medium none;
    padding: 0;
}
body .one .bsa_it_ad .bsa_it_t {
    padding: 6px 0 0;
}
body .one .bsa_it_p {
    display: none;
}
.one .bsa_it_ad {
    color: #F5F7FA;
    padding: 4px 0 0 !important;
}
body #bsap_aplink,
body #bsap_aplink:hover {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    left: 104px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 45px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 100px;
}
.css_small {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.45em;
}
.css_vsmall {
    font-size: 65%;
    line-height: 1.45em;
}
#dt_example #container {
    margin: 64px auto 30px !important;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color: #034e7c;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: 115px;

    // filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#D73000', endColorstr='#FFFFFF',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   

}
.header img.logo {
    height: 105px;
}
.header ul.breadcrumb li a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #4a4a4a
}
.header ul.log-in {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.header ul li {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
    margin-right: 35px;
}
.header ul.log-in li,
.header ul.log-in li a {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none
}
.header .dateButton,
.dateButton {
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #e63308;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodâ€¦EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e63308 0%, #db3304 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #e63308), color-stop(100%, #db3304));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e63308 0%, #db3304 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e63308 0%, #db3304 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e63308 0%, #db3304 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e63308 0%, #db3304 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e63308', endColorstr='#db3304', GradientType=0);
    float: right;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.header .dateButton a,
.dateButton a {
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.header .dateButton img,
.dateButton img {
    padding-right: 5px
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
}
.footer p {
    color: #4a4a4a;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.footer p a {
    color: #9fcf64;
}
.navigation {
    min-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
    height: 60px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0%, #ececec 10%, #ededed 100%);
}
.navigation ul.breadcrumb {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
}
.navigation ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    color: #4a4a4a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.triangle {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 0 3px 5.2px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #4a4a4a;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.top-section {
    height: 100px;
}
body * {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #393c3d;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.bg-photo{
    background:url(http://planet.nu/dev/test/images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}
.bg-photo:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; 
}
.loginText{
    font-size: 16px;
}
#createCampaignButton {
    transition-property: background-color, color;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    font-size: 18px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    color: #fff;
    background: #8bbd3a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
   table{
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
              }
              h1{
                  color: #4a4a4a;
                  font-size: 48px;
              }
              table th{
                color: #666666;
                padding-top: 10px;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 15px;
              }
              table td {
                  padding-left: 15px;
                  
              }
              table td input{
                padding-left: 5px;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 22px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                width: 100%;
              }
              tbody{    
                  width: 95%;
                  display: table;
              }
```

```html
       <div class="header">
            <div class="top-section">
                <img class="logo" src="http://planet.nu/dev/test/images/littleforest_logo.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-photo col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <h1 style="font-size: 35px; text-align:center; color:#FFF;margin:20px 0 0 0">
                    Welcome to LFi
                </h1>
                <p style="text-align:center; color: #FFF; font-size: 20px; padding: 28px 0 0 0;">Insight that drives web success</p>
                <br>
                <form method="post" action="/crawler/LoginServlet">
                    <table style="width: 40%; padding: 20px 30px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: 30px 0 0 0; background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    User Name
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput loginText" placeholder="User Name">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Password
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="textInput loginText" placeholder="Password">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        <p class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" name="commit" class="button" id="createCampaignButton" value="Log in" style="width:260px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <p>
                Powered by <a href="http://www.littleforest.co.uk/" style="color: #65892a; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;">Little Forest</a> a tool that encourages continuous improvement towards web success.
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What can come in handy in situation like this is css property vh.

Depends on which browsers you have to support, but to adjust to height of view port you can do `height: 100vh` or `vmin`.

More details on browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: I didn't know there's such an option. The problem still remains as it doesn't adjust to the height of the screen automatically. It's the same as adjusting the height of .bg-photo. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve sticky-footer without any plugins. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mqfrnjaa/15/) i did "sticky footer and header" only with css. One can add up more content under the form and get assured that the page stretches right down while content stays above the footer - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mqfrnjaa/16/embedded/result/).

```
    /**sticky-footer layout**/
body {
min-height: 500px;  
} 

.header,
#main,
.footer {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
height:120px !important; 
overflow:hidden;
background:#ffffff !important;
position:relative;
z-index: 10;
padding:0 !important;
 opacity:0.9;
}

.footer {
height:100px !important;
background:#ffffff !important;
overflow:hidden;
opacity:0.9;
padding:0 !important;
}

#main {
  min-height:100%;
  margin:-120px 0 -100px;
  height:auto !important;

}

#main:after,
#main:before {
content:"";
display:block !important;
margin:0;
}

#main:before {
height:120px;
}

#main:after {
height:100px;
}
```

However, you might not like the fact that your bg container .bg-photo#main lays underneath header and footer (which i made opaque on purpose to demonstrate, how the blocks are positioned), thus cutting bits of your leaves background. 
You would instinctively wish to transfer the background to an inner immediate div inside the main section. I've sketched this [eventuality](https://jsfiddle.net/mqfrnjaa/18/) as well, however since it's uses vh units,

```
min-height: calc( 100vh - 220px);
```

it might not work in all browsers, so beware, i also used calc to subtract the header and the footer. I hope it'll work reliably for you.